# Tee Command in mysql batch file is not working

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I am having mysql batch file nameed data.sql which contains below data

```
tee /var/lib/MYSQLBACKUP/info.txt;
USE APR_PHASE_II ;
INSERT INTO PRODUCTDETAILS (ITEM_CODE,ITEM_DESC) VALUES ('WT002','Water for Injection USP');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTDETAILS (ITEM_CODE,ITEM_DESC) VALUES ('WT003','Water for Injection USP');
```

when i execute data.sql script using below command

```
mysql -u root -ppass < /var/lib/data.sql;
```

it will insert data into table PRODUCTDETAILS but did not store output of execution into info.txt file since we are executing first tee command into batch file it should redirect output to info.txt

If i login into mysql command prompt and then executes batch file statement one by one individually it will redirect output to info.txt , can anyone guide me in this problem ?

Mysql version is 5.1 and OS is fedora 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch mode doesn't produce any output (cf. "Query OK, 1 Row Affected" in interactive mode), unless errors occur, so there's nothing to see.

It does, however, stop and write a message to `STDERR` on the first error -- in contrast to using the `source` command in interactive mode, which keeps running.

If a batch applied using `<` redirection into the `mysql` command line client hits an error, execution will stop, and the shell variable `$?` will contain a non-zero value.  It will contain '0' on success.

The `STDERR` stream can be captured to a file using the `2>` redirect

```
$ mysql < deliberate_error_in_here.sql 2>err.txt
```

Nothing shows on the console, but the exit status variable is set to 1.

```
$ echo $?
1
```

The file I named "err.txt" contains the error.

```
$ cat err.txt
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'foo' 
at line 1
```

On windows, instead of `$?` you'd check `%ERRORLEVEL%` for a nonzero value if an error occurred.

Whether this is useful information really depends on what you're trying to do.  If you're just using batch mode but actually doing this manually, then using `tee` and then using `source {filename}` to apply the file might be closer to what you're looking for, since it does show the output, but it doesn't show the actual statement being executed, since you didn't actually type it (it only shows you using the `source` command, followed by all of the normal output resulting from executing each of those commands).

Comment: I do have one more question , so i will not have log of batch file execution with status of how many query will be executed successfully and how many are failed ?

Comment: It will stop at the first error in batch mode.  If the `$?` value is zero, there were no errors.